# evalML no module named pymeeus

Tags: python, evalml

I just installed a new conda enviroment with python 3.9, compatible with evalML. I installed evalML with pip because conda was failing and I took care to intall "Windows Additional Requirements & Troubleshooting" before. https://evalml.alteryx.com/en/stable/install.html During the installation process a module named pymeeus is installed.

if I now try to install it manually, I have :

```
(evalML) C:\Users\G>pip install pymeeus
Requirement already satisfied: pymeeus in c:\users\g\anaconda3\envs\evalml\lib\site-packages (0.5.12)
```

But when I try to run it from the same command window after running python:

```
>>> from pymeeus.Epoch import Epoch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymeeus'
```

how to fix it ?